# Extend map from other packages at compile time

Tags: dictionary, go, composite-literals

I'm trying to extend a map across packages at 'compile time'. Is this possible?

I have package `A` with a predefined map:

```
package A

var MyMap = map[string]string{"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}
```

And I would like to extend the map during 'compile time'. This shall be done in another package. E.g. like so (not working code ofc.):

```
package B

import "A"

A.MyMap.Slice1["key3"] = "value" // extend the map during compile time
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this "at compile" time. In fact, the composite literal that `package A` uses, that also will be constructed and used at runtime. There are no composite literal constants.

Going further, whatever code you write in package `B`, if it imports package `A`, code of package `B` will only run after package `A` has been initialized, including the map you posted.

If you want `A.MyMap` to have a different value before it can be seen by any other package, you should modify the source of package `A`. This could be a generated additional file, which could use a package `init()` function, assigning a new value to `MyMap`, or adding new values to it.

If you can, you could also modify package `A` so that the initialization of `MyMap` is moved to a different source file, one that can be generated.

Comment: Meaning the map of `package A` will be constructed upon first interaction with the package? Or at import?

Comment: Package `A` will be initialized before any other package could reference anything from it.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually extension at runtime but it should fit your example.

Use [init](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init) function.

```
package B

import "A"

func init() {
    A.MyMap["key3"] = "value"
}
```

Comment: That one is working ofc. I intentionally need it at compile time :-/ I tried init() but failed to have this one being called without the package actually being imported. I guess I'll have to find a way around it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You pass a string at linking time with command

```
go build -ldflags '-X somemap={"k":"v"}'
```

and then parse it to map at run time. You can easily use JSON format.

See more on [GcToolchainTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GcToolchainTricks#including-build-information-in-the-executable).

Comment: When I try this, I get `main.m: cannot set with -X: not a var of type string (type:map[string]string)`